# Is there a way to wire Date.getTime()'s value in Spring Context?

Tags: java, spring

I was wondering is there a way to wire `Date.getTime()` value in a spring context.
This is my bean below.

```
<bean id="date" class="java.util.Date/>
```

Can I wire the value of `date.getTime()` by any way?

Comment: Try Spring Expression Language (SpEL).

Comment: getTime()'s return type you can set into class attribute's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [SpEL expressions in XML configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based)

A property or constructor-arg value can be set using expressions as shown below.

```
<bean id="numberGuess" class="org.spring.samples.NumberGuess">
<property name="randomNumber" value="#{ T(java.lang.Math).random() * 100.0 }"/>

<!-- other properties -->
</bean>
```

The variable systemProperties is predefined, so you can use it in your expressions as shown below. Note that you do not have to prefix the predefined variable with the # symbol in this context.

```
<bean id="taxCalculator" class="org.spring.samples.TaxCalculator">
<property name="defaultLocale" value="#{ systemProperties['user.region'] }"/>

<!-- other properties -->
</bean>
```

You can also refer to other bean properties by name, for example.

```
<bean id="numberGuess" class="org.spring.samples.NumberGuess">
<property name="randomNumber" value="{ T(java.lang.Math).random() * 100.0 }"/>

<!-- other properties -->
</bean>
<bean id="shapeGuess" class="org.spring.samples.ShapeGuess">
<property name="initialShapeSeed" value="{ numberGuess.randomNumber }"/>

<!-- other properties -->
</bean>
```

Comment: Try not to write link-only answers. Add all necessary information to answer this question in your post and keep this link for further information. Always ask yourself: is this answer helpful, if the link ends up with a 404.

Comment: Sure, will do next time. Sorry!